# Recursively looking for count of file extension using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Looking to get a PowerShell snippet that will list all file extensions recursively in a folder along with the count.

```
/abc/(1).cfc
/abc/john/(265).cfm, (1).html
/abc/john/js/(25).js
/abc/john/css/(6).css
```

This is what I've tried so far, but I'm not sure how to add the path for each:

```
Get-Childitem "C:\projects\newfolder\edit" -Recurse |
    where { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    group Extension -NoElement |
    sort count -Desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to achieve the expected output:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\TempFiles" -Recurse -File | Group-Object DirectoryName |
ForEach-Object { 
    "{0}\{1}" -f $_.Name,
     (($_.Group | Group-Object Extension | 
        ForEach-Object { ("({0}){1}" -f $_.Count, $_.Name) }) -join ",")
}
```

*Output*

```
C:\TempFiles\Root\(1).json,(2).html,(2).txt
C:\TempFiles\Root\Folder1\(4).json,(2).html,(2).txt,(2).png
C:\TempFiles\Root\Folder1\Folder1-1\(2).json,(2).html
C:\TempFiles\Root\Folder2\(2).txt
```

Comment: I had to remove the -File parameter to get it to work. How can I put a double line break after each last right directory?

Comment: You can use `n for putting line-break in a string.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you have never upvoted an answer. Just for your information, when you accept an answer, you can also upvote the accepted answer. It's not compulsory at all, but it's [recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) and common.

Answer (score 3):

The answer posted by @AnsgarWiechers is OK if you want the list of matching files as well as the count; if you only want the directory name and the count,

(Powershell v2:)

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\projects\newfolder\edit' -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Group-Object DirectoryName, Extension |
    Select-Object Name, Count
```

(PowerShell v3+:)

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\projects\newfolder\edit' -Recurse -File |
    Group-Object DirectoryName, Extension |
    Select-Object Name, Count
```

Comment: I am using powershell 4. I get this error
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

Comment: The '-' is significant. `-File`, not `File`.

Comment: Hi Raza, in your script where would I put the `n at? Also, how do I upvote an answer?

Comment: Upvotes are done by clicking on the upward-pointing triangle next to the answer to be upvoted. Doing so earns a few points of SO reputation for the person who posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by multiple criteria:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\projects\newfolder\edit' -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Group-Object DirectoryName, Extension
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer the filtering can be done directly with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\projects\newfolder\edit' -Recurse -File |
    Group-Object DirectoryName, Extension
```